# How to avoid using spaces as separators in zsh for-loop?

Tags: for-loop, sh, zsh, separator

I'm trying to make a little script to convert some files from a music library.

But If I do something like :

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh                                                                     

for x in $(find -name "*.m4a");
do
    echo $x;
done
```

When interpreting in a folder containing :

```
foo\ bar.m4a
```

it will return :

```
foo
bar.m4a
```

How could I prevent the for loop from interpreting space characters as separators?

I could replace `$(find -name "*.m4a")` with `$(find -name "*.m4a" | sed "s/ /_/g")` and then using `sed` the other way inside the loop, but what if file names/paths already contain underscores (Or other characters I may use instead of underscore)?

Any idea?

Comment: People will jump your case for using a for loop on the output of `find`.. If you can, use find's internal -exec feature to execute commends while using it. The feature is portable across find implementation and helps forgo the problems you are experiencing with parsing `for` loops and file name whitespace. That all being said. one can set the IFS variable to get fine grain control over the what delimiter the shell uses for tokenization. Generally the simplest usage of IFS is to just set it to nothing exactly like this:  IFS=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zsh`'s globbing facilities here instead of `find`.

```
for x in **/*.m4a; do
    echo "$x"
done
```

Quoting `$x` in the body of the loop is optional under the default settings of `zsh`, but it's not a bad idea to do so anyway.

Comment: Nice one! I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 7):

You can prevent word splitting of the command substitution by double-quoting it:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh                                                                     

for x in "$(find . -name "*.m4a")"
do
    echo "$x"
done
```

Notice that the double quotes inside the command substitution don't conflict with the double quotes outside of it (I'd actually never noticed this before now). You could just as easily use single quotes if you find it more readable, as in `"$(find -name '*.m4a')"`. I usually use single quotes with `find` primaries anyway.

Quoting inside the loop body is important for the same reason. It will ensure that the value of `x` is passed as a single argument.

But this is definitely a hybrid, Frankensteinian solution, and looping over the output of `find` is generally considered unsafe. You'd be better off with either [shell filename generation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33129044/2954547) or using `find` as follows:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec echo {} \;
```

You can add additional `-exec` primaries, which will be executed like shell commands that are separated by `&&`.

If you absolutely must loop over `find` output, use null-delimited output instead of newline-delimited:

```
touch 'a b.txt'
touch $'b\nc.txt'
touch $'d\te.txt'

find . -name '*.txt' -print0 \
| while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' fname; do
    printf '%s\n\n' "$fname"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out.

As suggested here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/344407/how-to-read-complete-line-in-for-loop-with-spaces

I may set the IFS (Internal Field Separator) to '\n'.

So this works :

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh                                                                                          

IFS=$'\n'
for x in $(find -name "*.m4a");
do
    echo $x;
done
```

I hope this could help someone else!

Comment: This doesn't work for files whose names contain newlines (rare, but legal).

Comment: @chepner newlines in filenames? i'm getting old

Comment: @Jonathan I'm not sure there was ever a time when they *weren't* legal; people just avoided them to make code easier to write.

Comment: If you do insist on looping over `find` output, at least use `-print0` and `IFS=`, to work with null-delimited instead of newline-delimited entries.